# Converting hex color code, to rgba and fetching the red value

Tags: sass

If I have a color code in `sass` in a hexadecimal format `#aaaaaa`, is there any way to convert this to an RGB format, and get only the red value number with a function?

An example on what I would like to achieve:

```
@function getRedValue($color) {
     // convert $color which will be provided in hexadecimal format, to rgba
     // return the red value of the color number
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some SASS [default color functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_functions_color.asp) you could use.

Please check `red()`, `green()` and `blue()`.